# Importing existing git repo into assembla

Tags: ruby, git, assembla

Currently I have an website on a .zip file containing also the .git directory and all the history. I want it to be imported into an Assembla git repository preserving the history of all previous changes. Is there an easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

extract your zip, navigate to it in your shell, and do `git push <git assembla url> :`. this should push all the refs to the new assembla repo.

Comment: I am trying to do so but I get:

No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.assembla.com:xxxx.git'

What else can I do?

Comment: @Jacobo Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.

Comment: you may need to update your .git/config file and remove an existing origin definition, just delete those lines.  Then follow instructions in assembla:
git remote add origin git@git.assembla.com:<your url>.git
git push origin master

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot push to an assembla repo, check your ssh keys, like in [this thread](http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2-Subversion/topics/444-Git--connection-closed-by-assembla?page=3).

> `ssh -v git@git.assembla.com`

And see if there was not too much login errors in your tries:

> Your IP was added to blacklist due login failure to our server.